# Describing image of line segment under $F: V \rightarrow W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

From S.L linear algebra:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $v,w \in V$. The
>   **line passing through** $v$ and **parallel** to $w$ is defined to be the set
>   of all elements $v+tw$ with $t \in R$. The line segment between $v$ and
>   $v+w$ is defined to be the set of all elements $v+tw$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Between what points?
>
> Let $L: V \rightarrow U$ be a linear map. Show that the image under
>   $L$ of a line segment in $V$ is a line segment in $U$. Show that the
>   image of a line under $L$ is either a line or a point. Between what
>   points?
>
> Show that the image of a line under L is either a line or a point.

---

Formally, I defined some arbitrary line segment $X \in V$ as:

$X=\{v+tw \mid v,w \in W \land 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$

Then, two axioms of linear mapping are:

1. $L(X)=L(X)+L(Y)$, for $Y \in V$.
2. $cL(X)=L(cX)=\{cv+ctw \mid v,w \in W \land 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$, for $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

But the the mapping itself isn't explicitly defined, the only clue is linearity that produces two axioms above (which by my assumption should show that the image under $L$ of a line segment in $V$ is a line segment in $U$).

---

How can I utilize limited information given from the book above in order to describe the image under $L$ of linear segment in a vector space? Is there any additional information that is a key to the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: $L(v+tw)=L(v)+tL(w)$

Comment: How can you write $L(v + tw)$ using 1. and 2.?

Comment: @leibnewtz But shouldn't restriction for $t$ be mentioned like my general definition above? Or they can be mentioned within the proof?

Comment: @TrevorGunn Generally for $v+tw$ it would be $L(v+tw)=L(v)+tL(w)$ like leibnewtz has stated. I assume restrictions for $t$ will be mentioned along with the proof. I'm guessing that is indeed sufficient evidence to prove that $L(v+tw)$ will result in some arbitrary line segment since $t$ is remains unaffected.

Comment: @ShellRox Be careful, you don't know what L is doing to the vectors. Either (or both) of L(v) and L(w) may be 0. You need to take care of those cases as well.

Comment: @JoelPereira So the assumption in the book that that the image under $L$ of a line segment in $V$ is a line segment in $U$ is incorrect unless $L(v) \neq O \land L(w) \neq O$?

Comment: @ShellRox I believe that we can consider a point as a $\textit{degenerate}$ line. Think of the point v as the line containing v and parallel to $\textbf{0}$. The statement said that show that the image is a line or a point.

Comment: @JoelPereira Thus it can be both line and a point (i.e point when it might be parallel to zero), which makes sense I believe. Thank you!